# How to display datalist in tabview using primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I'm stuck with this problem since eight days..I'm not able to  display the `datalist` in `tabview`, I tried this but still not working.

```
<p:tabView><p:tab title="Userlogin">
    <ui:include src="userlogin/list.xhtml"/>
</p:tab></p:tabView>
```

this is my user login list file
can anyone help me out ?

Comment: this is my userlogin list file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="title">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserloginTitle}"></h:outputText>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="body">

Comment: you can edit your question... And please read [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question. Reading your own question again and thinking whether you would be able to answer it helps to.. Or asking a colleague first